# How to scan qr code efficiently using front camera in android

Tags: android

My Qr scan working efficiently in back camera but it is pretty bad when using front cam. Obviously resolution is different for both.It is 5MP for back cam and 0.3 MP for other one.I have to use front cam..have no other option..Currently i am using Zxing library...Plzz help me guys

Comment: use some simple QR code with lesser values

Comment: Is it working with the back camera

Comment: you need to change in library which is using by you because camera will manage through Zxing lib

Comment: @Vinay..currently i am using simple qr code

Comment: @dileep.yeah...it is working with back cam..why did u ask??

Comment: What is the error correction you have given? reducing error correction probably should work in favor of you

Comment: I havent got any errors..it is woking..but very badly..it usually takes long time to scan the code